# Не могу разобраться с особенностями Scanner. Почему здесь выходит "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, исключения, scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;    

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float x = getFloatValue("Узнаем стоимость x %s/шт. - ", "RUB", 0, 10_000, false); // Здесь всё хорошо, метод работает
        System.out.println(x);

        float y = getFloatValue("Узнаем стоимость y %s/шт. - ", "USD", 0, 10_000, false); 
        //      А ЗДЕСЬ У МЕНЯ ВЫХОДИТ ОШИБКА:
        //      Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        //      at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
        //      at TestClass.getFloatValue(TestClass.java:30)
        //      at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:12)
        System.out.println(y);
    }

    static float getFloatValue(String text, String sCurrency, float start, float end, boolean including) {       
        boolean a = false;
        float x=0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (!a) {
            System.out.printf(text, sCurrency);
            String str = in.nextLine();

            try {
                x = Float.valueOf(str.trim().replace(",", "."));

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println("Ошибка принятия значения. Необходим повторный ввод."); }
            if(including == true && x>=start && x<=end) {a = true; }
            else if(including == false && x>start && x<end) {a = true; }
            else { System.out.println("Ошибка! Необходимо ввести корректное значение."); }
        }
        in.close();
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите строку  in.close(); и все заработает. Сам сканнер не является ресурсом, требующим освобожения. Таковым является InputStream переданный в него. И закрывая сканнер, вы закрываете непосредственно stream. И переоткрыть его не получится. Соответственно у вас когда отработал метод getFloatValue() первый раз - вы закрываете stream и во время работы метода во второй раз уже не можете его открыть. И получаете исключение

Comment: Захожу сейчас как раз-таки написать про in.close(); и спросить, отчего же это ошибка!xD И вижу ваш ответ. Спасибо!!! А нужно ли in.close(); писать в конце основного метода main???

Comment: При передаче System.in сканеру - не нужно